# Permission dialog shows out from activity in android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am asking for run time permission. It is asking for the permission and everything is good. But the problem is that the permission dialog is somehow showing outside of the Activity. It close the Activity and then show the dialog of permission. I want that dialog to be show in my activity.

This is my Code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);
    setPasswordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setPasswordText);
    setSecurityText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setSecurityText);
    messageToSendText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageToSendText);
    numberToSendText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberToSendText);
    /* if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
        startService(intent);
    } */

    KING();
}

// @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void KING() {
    // Toast.makeText(this, "Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "RECEIVE SMS permission is needed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_SEND_SMS){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION GRANTED BY YOU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION DENIED BY YOU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Closes the activity? Are you sure? As far as I know, it just pauses the activity.

Comment: Alright. Even if it pause it. Actually, the layout of the Activity is not going to show but only the permission dialog box.

Comment: Try to move that `KING()` method to `onResume()`

Comment: You mean like this: public void onResume(){
        KING();
    }

Comment: yea, after `super.onResume();`

Comment: App crashes. It gives error of "Unable to resume activity"

Comment: Did you add call to super class?

Comment: Yes, I did this:  public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        KING();
    }

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem. Closes my activity. Once the permission is granted then the next time the activity works normally.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this solves your problem but it solved mine. For historical reasons which I had long forgotten I had the following flag set on my activity

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

This means that as soon as the activity is not in the foreground it closes. So when the permission dialog popped up, my activity went down. The answer was to get rid of that flag. It only took me two days of frustration to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seem to have found a fix...

Overriding the `onRequestPersmissionsResult` function solves both of my problems.

First of all the dialog now appears in front of my activity screen.

Secondly, I am now able to control what happens based on whether the user grants or denies the requested permission.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
        if(requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION){
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
//                Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION GRANTED BY YOU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Opening app without location permission...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, websiteViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

I'll need to tweak the logic a bit as I add the extra permissions, but this has got me a good starting point and solves the two immediate problems.